# How to solve this differential equation, involving leibniz notation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I thought I was pretty good at calculus, but this one has stumped me. I can do many *almost* identical examples, but I can't seem to extrapolate the skills needed to this one tricky problem.

$${dy \over dx} = y+2$$

The solution is listed in the book as $y=Ce^x-2$

I can't seem to wrestle the equation into any kind of form that I know how to work with, which is frustrating as I realize this is quite simple.

I want to multiply by dx, but it just seems to complicate things.

Comment: If so, not by that name. I think the issue I am having involves the separation of variables, and the fact that y is on the right hand side of the equation. I know that I want to pull like variables together and then integrate both sides, but I can't seem to wrestle it how I would need to. Were the right hand side $x+2$ this would be a much easier problem.

Comment: how about $\frac{dy}{y+2} = dx?$

Comment: D'oh! That's what you get when you take algebra 1 in middle school I guess, you forget it all.

Comment: How about setting $z(x)=y(x)+2$? Then you get $dz/dx=z$, which is a differential equation that I hope you can solve. ("Which function $z(x)$ equals its own derivative?") Or use the method of integrating factor. Or use the the characteristic polynomial ("homogeneous + particular solution"). Or use separation of variables (as already suggested in the answers). Etc.

Comment: I follow you Hans, but that seems like a runaround way to do it, and quite confusing.

Comment: Not confusing to me. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a first-order linear ordinary differential equation, and it is separable. You may write it as: $$\frac{dy}{y+2}=dx$$ Then, integrate both sides. Thus, you have that: $$\int \frac{dy}{y+2}=\int dx$$ $$\ln\left|y+2\right|=x+C$$ $$\left|y+2\right|=e^{x+C}=e^Ce^x \iff y+2=\pm e^Ce^x=c_1e^x \iff y=c_1e^x-2$$

Comment: Ah! As always, my mistake lies not in my skills in calculus, but my skills in algebra! I failed to see that you could divide by $y+2$! I've never been great at algebra. I didn't even consider division as an option, only subtraction. Thank you!

Comment: Damn,beat me to it..............lol

Comment: Actually one should be a bit more careful with absolute value signs for this to be a complete solution. (What about the case $y<-2$?)

Comment: @HansLundmark Good point,but unless it's otherwise specified, in a problem for beginners like this, I think we can assume WLOG that $y \geq -2$. But in general, you're absolutely right.

Comment: A better way to do it would be
$$|y+2| = e^{x+C} \Rightarrow y = \pm e^Ce^x - 2 = c_1e^x - 2$$
where $c_1 = \pm e^C$ can be positive or negative

Comment: @Dylan  Right on the mark,but I doubt at his/her level, the OP has to worry about these kinds of technicalities. Still-important to point out.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a fairly easy ordinary differential equation-it is what we call a separable equation.i.e. the variables can be "separated" as follows: 
                   $$dx = \frac {1}{y+2}dy$$

Integrating both sides gives x = In (y+2) + C . Taking the natural exponential of both sides gives:
             $e^{x}$ = $e^{c}(y+2)$

Multiplying through by $e^{-c}$ gives:
             $e^{-c}e^{x}$ = y+2

Now we simply rearrange the equation and collect terms to give the answer in your book. Do it yourself, it's just algebra.

Ain't calculus grand?

Answer (score 2):

These equations are almost always solved by collecting the same variables on either side of the equation so that it results in a normal expression. In this case you would want to write it as: 
$$\frac{dy}{y+2}=dx$$
Then you can integrate both sides with respect to each variable to get:
$$\int\frac{dy}{y+2}=\int dx$$
$$ln(y+2)+lnC=x$$
$$y=Ce^x-2$$