# Differential and Differential Equation - Difference in meaning?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am a little confused, an exercise by a teacher has been set which says:

For $X_t = 2e^{B_t}$
Where $B_t$ is brownian motion at time $t$.

a) Find the stochastic differential $d(X_t)$

b) Find the stochastic differential equation for $X_t$

I have completed the first exercise, but am confused as to what the difference between the two is?

for a)

$$d(2e^{B_t}) = 2e^{B_t}dB_t + e^{B_t} dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The not-so-exact calculation goes as
$$
d(2e^{B_t})=2e^{B_{t+dt}}-2e^{B_t}=2e^{B_t}(e^{dB_t}-1)\\
=2e^{B_t}\Bigl(1+dB_t+\tfrac12(dB_t)^2+O((dB_t)^3)-1\Bigr)
$$
and using the rules $dB_t^2=dt$ and to ignore all higher powers results in
$$
d(2e^{B_t})=2e^{B_t}(dB_t+\tfrac12 dt)=e^{B_t}dt+2e^{B_t}dB_t
$$
as you also computed, probably using the Ito formula.

Using $X_t$ to get rid of the exponentials gives the SDE
$$
dX_t=X_t(\tfrac12 dt+dB_t)
$$

Comment: Nice, I think I almost had it before (in the comments below), but was just lacking the proper idea behind it.

This will help me in preparation for my exam, and I won't be making the same mistake again :)

Answer (score 1):

The differential is a linear mapping that approximates a differentiable function in a given nieghborhood of a point. In this question, you're being asked to construct this linear mapping.

A differential equation,on the other hand, is a equation of a given function in terms of the derivative or derivatives of a given order of a given function of one or several variables with specified boundary conditions. The antiderivative-if it exists-is the function which is the solution of the equation. So a differential equation is a much more specific construction.

Comment: Would it be of the form:

$$d(X_t) = X_t dX_t + \frac{1}{2} X_t dt$$ ?

Comment: It might very well be,but to be honest,I know next to nothing about stochastic processes. Any probabilists on the board want to help the OP out?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't 100% understand what you actually meant.

Would you be able to provide an example of a differential vs differential equation, even it is isn't a stochastic one

Comment: Well,a nice simple example of a differential equation can be found here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247195/how-to-solve-this-differential-equation-involving-leibniz-notation/1247216#1247216  A good brief discussion of differentials for functions of 2 variables with  examples can be found here:   http://calculus7.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/diffntl2varlect.pdf